# accessing char* or char array in struct C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, char

ok im having a problem i cant figure out. i have a struct in header file.

```
typedef struct client_t{
char cName[MAX_BRNAME];
char cLname[MAX_BRNAME];
int id;
int clientBrNum;            
int accNum;                 
unsigned int creditLim;     
int accBalance;             
int sumLoans;               
int closedBalance;  }CLIENT;
```

now when i try to access either cName or cLname in another function i get 
Field 'cName' could not be resolved. all other variables accessible.

```
void addNewClientToBranch(CLIENT bcList ,char* cNam,char* lNam,int cId,int aNum,){
int i;
for (i=0;i<500;i++){
    if(bcList[i]==0){
        bcList[i].cName=cNam;
        bcList[i].cLname=lNam;
        bcList[i].id=cId;
        bcList[i].accNum=aNum;
        return;
    }
}
printf("branch full\n");
return;     }
```

at first i tried to do it with char* in struct still wouldnt work?

Comment: Those are arrays. You can't assign to an array like that. You have to loop over it and assign to `bcList[i].cName[j]`. Or you probably want to copy a string using `strcpy`.

Comment: Not sure what you hope `if(bcList[i]==0)` is doing either. `bcList` itself isn't an array according to the definition of what a `CLIENT` is that you posted at the top of your question, and the `CLIENT bcList` argument to your function. In fact, *none* of the `bcList[i]` usage in this post could possibly work.

Comment: right i got that wrong in the if... i meant to check id

Comment: You have some sort of project dependency goof up. From the file where `addNewClientToBranch` is located, do you include the header with `CLIENT`? Or are they in the same file?

Comment: Also, passing structs by value like this is very bad practice. Please provide a [mvce] demonstrating how you want to call this function. Where is the magic number 500 coming from?

Comment: included the header ... seems like a compiler bug in eclipse. meant to send struct array to function, fixed now.

Comment: warning function returns value of local variable is because i didnt pass by reference ?

Comment: Please show the code that calls `addNewClientToBranch`. The answer possibly depends on this information. Also read this: why is it useful du provide a [mcve].